# __getitem__ error in win32com powerpoint object library

Tags: python, powerpoint, pywin32

Trying to get a working version of [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0460__Windows/PowerPointExample.htm)

Using the code exactly as quoted, I'm getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    ppoint()
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 9, in ppoint
    s1a = s1.Shapes[0].TextFrame.TextRange
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 465, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library.Shapes instance at 0x36209528>' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Win32com is importing fine - any thoughts much appreciated!

Comment: Clueless about Python, so maybe way off base, but if it's asking PowerPoint for SomeSlide.Shapes(0) that might be the issue.  PowerPoint's collections (slides, shapes, etc) are 1-based.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've run into the same problem. After checking out the COM api from MSDN, I found it's the syntax that has errors. The correct code from your cited page should be:

```
...
s1 = pres.Slides.Add(1, win32.constants.ppLayoutText)
sleep(1)
s1a = s1.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
s1a.Text = 'Python-to-%s Demo' % app
sleep(1)
s1b = s1.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange
for i in RANGE:
     s1b.InsertAfter("Line %d\r\n" % i)
     sleep(1)
s1b.InsertAfter("\r\nTh-th-th-that's all folks!")
...
```

Shapes[1] should be Shapes(1). and Rindsberg is right. COM API for PowerPoint's collections should start with 1.